# Selecting different values from different columns

Tags: oracle

I need a query to select different values from different columns as shown below:

```
timestamp          queues           queuesname        groupnumb
23-01-2014         FNG              CGI               15467P
24-02-2014         ACS              GHK               15467P
26-02-2014         ERT              FNG               15467P
01-03-2014         ACS              TYU               15467P
04-05-2014         TYI              GHK               15467P
```

I need the the row with queues = ACS (latest one has timestamp 01-03-2014) and queuesname = GHK (latest one has timestamp 04-05-2014)

For the above example I need this output:

```
Min_timestamp      max_timestamp       queues       queuesname    groupn
01-03-2014         04-05-2014          ACS          GHK           15467P
```

I don't need a hard coded query.

Comment: what do you mean you don't need a hard coded query?

Comment: Now that i reread it, I just don't understand the question

Comment: Why isn't the first `queues='ACS'` row selected (24-02-2014) instead of the 2nd one? Do you mean you want the newest ACS row as min and newest GHK as Max timestamp, for the same group name? You're going to have to explain the logic better, as it stands it isn't answerable

Answer (score 4):

It's not very clear what you are after but here's a query under my understanding that you want to find the last timestamp where `queues = 'ACS'` and the last timestamp where `queuesname = 'GHK'` for every `groupnumb`:

```
with grp as
  ( select groupnumb, max(timestamp) as timestamp
    from tableX
    where queues = 'ACS'
    group by groupnumb
  union all
    select groupnumb, max(timestamp)        
    from tableX
    where  queuesname = 'GHK'
    group by groupnumb
  )
select min(timestamp) as min_timestamp,
       max(timestamp) as max_timestamp,
       groupnumb
from grp
group by groupnumb ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should give you what you need

```
SELECT 
 max(CASE WHEN queues = 'ACS' THEN timestamp END) AS min_timestamp,
 max(CASE WHEN queuesname = 'GFK' THEN timestamp END) as max_timestamp, 
 'ASC' AS queues ,'GFK' AS queuesname ,groupnumb
FROM  tableX
GROUP BY groupnumb
```